# ¿Cómo usar el ShowDataPicker en Español con Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart

En mi proyecto de Flutter WEB, muestro un selector de fecha (`ShowDataPicker`), el mismo siempre aparece en ingles, a pesar que importe el paquete  `flutter_localizations`.

Es posible que me este faltando algún detalle que no alcanzo a comprender. ¿Qué debería hacer?

Aqui mi Main 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que intentas hacer funcionara perfectamente para aplicaciones móviles, pero actualmente **Locale para Flutter web aun no a sido implementado**, tal y como se puede ver continuación.

```
// TODO(flutter_web): Get the real locale from the browser.
```

https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/lib/web_ui/lib/src/ui/window.dart#L705

Te recomiendo seguir el PR acerca del tema. 
[issues/48886](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48886)

Comment: muchas gracias! no habia advertido eso. Buscare otra alternativa